# issues with translate / line-height when changing position when hovered on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This problem is only with chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ew5o6as/

Basically, when you hover the `.tile`, it should show the `.caption` below. It works out fine, but it wont return to its original state as it should. If you look closely, it shows about 1-2 pixels after mouseout.

What I seemed to have noticed is that the problem disappears whenever I remove the `translate:transform` on the `.wrap` or whenever I remove the `line-height:50px` on `.caption`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your browser window zoomed in / out? I know this can sometimes cause alignment issues...

Comment: @JeremyBlalock nope, but since you mentioned it, I checked, it works fine for other zoom levels. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

For different zoom levels, sometimes the values of transform and absolute positioning don't quite match up. To fix this, you can just add a `1px` 'margin of error' to the bottom:

```
.tile .caption {
    ...
    bottom: -51px;
    ....
}
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyblalock/3ew5o6as/1/

Comment: Thats is what Im currently using, but it feels weird and dirty and was hoping for an actual fix, cause its fine on other browsers...